# Haskell: Implementing an Applicative List

Tags: haskell, applicative

This is a self-motivated exercise.  To get the final case of `<*>` to work, I resorted to implementing `concatenation` as an auxiliary function.  Have I missed a trick?  That is, could that case have been written without needing an auxiliary function or be written in some other way?  (BTW, my principle reference is the [Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell), if that's relevant.)

The code:

```
    data List a = Empty | Item a (List a)
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

    instance Functor List where
        fmap ab Empty       = Empty
        fmap ab (Item a la) = Item (ab a) (fmap ab la)

    instance Applicative List where
        pure a                    = Item a Empty
        Empty       <*> _         = Empty
        _           <*> Empty     = Empty
        Item ab lab <*> Item a la = -- this is the case in question
            Item (ab a) (concatenation (ab <$> la) (lab <*> Item a la))
```

I guess what it comes down to is that, as far as I can recall in my limited experience, I've not needed an auxiliary function to implement any kind of instance so using one here makes me wonder whether it's necessary ...

Comment: I assume your `concatenation` function is just your type's version of `(++)`. There's no problem here; whatever else you did would just include a reimplementation of `concatenation` anyway.

Comment: (For what it's worth, the `Applicative []` instance in `GHC.Base` "cheats" by using a list comprehension: `fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]`.)

Comment: Remember, the goal here is to apply `ab` to ever element of `Item a la`; you are applying `ab` to `a` *and* mapping `ab` over `la`. Why not just map `ab` over `Item a la` all at once? (Which is to say, your definition of `<*>` is reimplementing part of `fmap` instead of *just* using `fmap`.)

Comment: @chepner: yes, your assumption is correct and thanks for the answers.  That's interesting about the use of comprehensions!  Still chewing over the last bit :)  BTW, if you put up a 'big' answer, I'll happily tick that.  Thanks again

Comment: @Rik The last bit is suggesting `Item ab lab <*> la = concatenation (ab <$> la) (lab <*> la)`. (This also lets you reduce the number of cases, as a second clause `Empty <*> _ = Empty` then covers everything in just two clauses instead of three.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: yes, so `Empty <*> _ = Empty` and `Item ab lab <*> la = concatenation (ab <$> la) (lab <*> la)`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to avoid auxiliary functions. However you define the instance, it either needs to use `concatenation`, or reimplement parts or all of its definition.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorter, equivalent version of the applicative instance for List.

```
instance Applicative List where
    pure a             = Item a Empty
    Empty       <*> _  = Empty
    Item ab lab <*> la = concatenation (ab <$> la) (lab <*> la)
```